# Having issues with pointers and tracking register values through a loop over strings

Tags: assembly, x86

This Assembly class is making me want to question this major. I thought this assignment was correct until she emailed me with "You do realize that esi and edi are never equal to g? They start out being 1000h and 2000h. Clearly you have not been paying attention. No credit".

Can someone help me correct what I did wrong? does that mean in the first two rows and columns, where I have esi and edi I put h? and if so is that all? or is there something else missing? She is extremely picky.

Here is what I have and as far as instructions are concerned, she just wants us to "decode" it which means to tell her exactly what's going on inside these registers.

---

Pretty much what we are doing is setting EAX and ECX to zero and then we go into a loop. ECX is first incremented by 1 and then its compared to 10. If ECX is less than 10 then ECX is then added to EAX and the loop will repeat until ECX is greater than 10. Then the current value of EAX moves into the variable called `Total` and prints the total.

```
     ; 2 parameters passed
     ; string1  ghost0  ("ghost") AT ADDRESS 1000 (goes into the ESI register)
     ; string2 ghostly0 ("ghostly") AT ADDRESS 2000 (goes into the EDI register)
                ; remember, C++ delineates the end of a string by adding zero

    _Task1  proc
    _asm
         Mov     bx,0        ; set return result to failed
        mov esi, DWORD PTR [esp + 4]    ; this is taking a passed pointer off the stack 
        mov edi, DWORD PTR [esp + 8]    ; this is taking a passed pointer off the stack 
                            esi edi al  ah
    L1:
        mov al, [esi]       g   g   g                    
        mov ah, [edi]       g   g   g   g               
        cmp al, 0           h   g   g   g
        jne L2              h   h   g   g
        cmp ah, 0           h   h   h   g
        jne L2              h   h   h   h
        mov     bx,1        o   h   h   h
        jmp L3              o   o   h   h
    L2:                     o   o   o   h
        inc esi             s   o   o   o
                inc edi     s   o   o   o
        cmp al, ah          s   s   o   o
            je  L1          s   s   s   o
    L3:                     t   s   s   s
            Ret             t   t   s   s
    _Task1  endp            t   t   s   s
            End             t   t   t   t   
Loop1 move the character    0   t   t   t                                       
from esi and edi            0   I   t   t
                            0   I   0   t
```

Loop1 moves char from esi and edi to the al and ah registers. The character assigned to the al register is then compared to 0. If the comparison is not equal than the program will jump to Loop2. Loop2 has esi and edi being incremented to the next character and al and ah are compared. Since al and ah are equal the program will jump to Loop1. This will repeat til al is equal to 0 in which the program will terminate.

Comment: It's not clear to me what those columns are supposed to represent.  But she is technically right that `esi` never contains the actual character `g` (i.e. the number 103), instead it initially contains the address of a byte in memory which contains `g`.  In C++ terms it's the difference between `esi == 'g'` (false) and `*esi == 'g'` (true).

Comment: Since you were specifically given the addresses for the strings, you should write `esi=1000` and `edi=2000` initially. It's unclear how you should mark the registers since this is a loop so of course those values will change. Not sure by what logic you wrote the letters anyway, as they don't correspond to the instructions on the same line at all.

Comment: You have a paragraph talking about EAX, ECX, and comparing to 10, but I don't see anything related to that in your code.